# Multiple Images in javascript from a rest API

Tags: javascript

[image: code to get the URI]
This is currently my code, it gives me the URL of a picture I need, and I call that in later.

[image: the code using the URI]

I call the code here and it projects an image to the app.

But this is just one image, I need a way to get multiple images (at least 30) to scroll through.

I'm unsure how to do this or how to start. I am thinking of saving an array of image outputs maybe.

I'm not entirely sure where to start, so I didn't get too far into testing.

I am entirely self-taught when it comes to javascript. So any help/advice would be huge.

Comment: Instead of adding image links, Please share the code as text.

Comment: [DO NOT use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Comment: Instead of just one url, send an array of URLs from the backend. Then in the frontend, iterate over that array and create elements dynamically

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(apiUrl)
  .then((response) => {
    // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    // Parse the JSON response
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < (data.length - 5); i++) {
      // Access specific data from the JSON response
      const image = data[i].guid.rendered;
      console.log(image);
      // Stack images at the front of the images array
      images.push(image);
    }
    console.log(images);
    return images;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

I did the loop, and it worked great! I just have some data to work with now in the backend!